# Dashboard display issues / layout / plot / reactive / UI

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

[image]I am trying to make a dashboard on shiny with 3 pages( dtable,sales,forecast), so far only the first - Data table shows.

The sales tab displays all the buttons, but there is no graph being displayed. Same goes for the forecast tab. Also, how could I tweak it, so all the buttons are on the left in a uniform manner followed by the graph?

Is my approach correct? Or should I use conditional panel ? Cant make heads or tails of whats wrong here.
I would like to make all 3 tabs responsive with their respective plots for now.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
   wmp <- read.csv("ABC.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## UI Basic Layout

```
     ui <- dashboardPage(skin=c("blue"),
    dashboardHeader(title = "Layout"),
     dashboardSidebar(id="",
                   sidebarMenu(menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "Data_Table", icon = icon("table")),
                              menuItem("Sales Performance", tabName = "Sales_Performance",icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
                              menuItem("Forecast",tabName = "Fore_Cast",icon = icon("bolt"))
                              )
                   ),
  #Main Body
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
                tabItem(tabName = "Data_Table",
                        box(title = "Data Table ",width=50,
                        column(2,
                       selectInput("PInput","Product:",c("All",unique(wmp$Product)))),
                        column(2,
                        selectInput("CInput","Category:",c("All",unique(wmp$Category)))),
                        column(4,
                        selectizeInput("PSCInput","Product Sub Category:",c("All",unique(wmp$sub.category))))), DT::dataTableOutput("table")),
                tabItem(tabName = "Sales_Performance",
                        sidebarMenu(fluidRow(title= "Sales Breakdown",width = 500,
                        column(4,    
                        sliderInput("monthInput","Month",min=1,max = 12,step = 1,c(25,45)),br()),
                        column(4,
                        selectizeInput("weekInput","Week",choices=unique(wmp$week),br())),
                        column(7,
                        selectizeInput("wdayInput","Week day",choices=unique(wmp$wday))),
                        column(4,
                        checkboxGroupInput("yearInput","Year",choices = unique(wmp$year))))),plotOutput("plot1")
                        #br(),br(),
                #tableOutput("Results")
                ),
                tabItem(tabName = "Fore_cast",width=400,
                        #UI buttons/options to be added later,
                        title="Plot2",plotOutput("plot2"))
                      )))
```

## Server reactive part

```
server <- function(input,output) {
   #For Data table
       output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
data1 <- wmp
if (input$PInput != "All") {
  data <- data1[data1$Product == input$PInput,] }
if (input$CInput != "All") {
  data <- data1[data1$Category == input$CInput,] }
if (input$PSCInput != "All") {
  data1 <- data1[data1$sub.category == input$PSCInput,] }
data1
}))
   #For interactive plot
    filtered <- reactive({ 
      if (is.null(input$yearInput)) {
      return(NULL)
      }    
    wmp %>%  filter(
    year == input$yearInput,
    week == input$weekInput,
  wday == input$wdayInput,
  month >= input$monthInput[1],
  month <= input$monthInput[2]
)})

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

wmp2 <- data.frame(filtered())
avg <- mean((wmp2$Amount))


  plotwmp2 <- ggplot(filtered(),aes(Date,Amount,group=filtered()$year,color=filtered()$year)) + scale_x_date() + geom_point() + geom_line() + xlab("Yearly Span") + theme_grey() + ggtitle("Weekly breakdown") + geom_hline(yintercept=avg,linetype="dashed", color = "red")


plotwmp2
})


   #For Time series, sample plot.
   output$plot2 <- renderPlot({ 

plot.ts(wmp$Amount)})}


   #Final App
   shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have buttons on left side and plot on the right, I think you should divide your page in two parts. Something like this:

```
tabItem(tabName = "Sales_Performance",
        fluidRow(title= "Sales Breakdown",width = 500,
           column(4,    
                  sliderInput("monthInput","Month",min=1,max = 12,step = 1,c(25,45)),
                  br(),
                  selectizeInput("weekInput","Week",choices=unique(wmp$week)),
                  br(),
                  selectizeInput("wdayInput","Week day",choices=unique(wmp$wday)),
                  br(),
                  checkboxGroupInput("yearInput","Year",choices = unique(wmp$year))
            ),
           column(8,
                  plotOutput("plot1")
           )
        )
)
```

Also you can put it in [boxes](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#boxes).

Problem with plots will be more easy to understand and fix if you will give a data sample. As far as I can judge the problems with plot2 should not be. 
There are extra characters at the end in plot1 code part "plotwmp2" right before closing brackets "})".

UPD. Plot2 doesn't appears because you has different tags in menuItem and tabItem - "Fore_Cast" and "Fore_cast" respectively.

About Plot1. When I run app, I see this: "Error:object 'Date' not found", so I looked at code output$plot1. You use this:
    aes(Date,Amount,group=filtered()$year,color=filtered()$year)
I corrected it to filtered()$Date,filtered()$Amount and plot has appear. But only if part

```
scale_x_date()
```

is commented. If I use "scale_x_date()", there are an error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only. Maybe you should to transform this column by mutate method.

Comment: I tried it out and the Sales tab looks much better now. The buttons are on the left and the graph on the side. But I cant seem to find the extra characters in the ggplot for plotwmp2 line :(  Please have a glance at the data sample I attach now and let me know. Do you have any other inputs regarding the 3rd tab, plot2 ?

Comment: @9minus4, I have updated my answer. I run this script and it works normally except   scale_x_date() method.

Comment: I see where I went wrong here, ^^ Thank you for updating your answer. I have made the necessary changes and they are all responsive now !  **But with plotwmp2 I get a new error :  " Warning: Error in match.arg: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector " 
 124: match.arg
    123: filter
    121: withVisible
    120: freduce
    118: eval
    117: eval
    116: withVisible
    115: %>%
    114: <reactive:filtered> [#18]
    103: filtered
    102: renderPlot [#28]
     92: <reactive:plotObj>
     81: plotObj
     80: origRenderFunc
     79: output$plot1

Comment: Found a solution to the match.arg error, It went away after the date column was transformed. It was not in 'Date' format. Thank you for all your inputs! @Olga :D